# Negative integers as the third parameter of np.r_? (numpy)

Tags: numpy

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

Negative integers specify where in the new shape tuple the last dimension of upgraded arrays should be placed, so the default is ‘-1’.

what does this sentence mean?

```
np.r_['0,2,-5', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ] # ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
np.r_['0,2,-6', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ] # array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]])
```

-5 and -6 both exceed the second parameter "2" in '0,2,-5', why -5 can not run ,but -6 can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description for this third value is a bit confusing, but with these list and the other numbers there are two possibilities (plus error cases):

```
In [31]: np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]         # or '0,2,-1'                                                             
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [32]: np.r_['0,2,0', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]                                                                    
Out[32]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

`[1,2,3]` as an array has shape (3,).  The '2' means expand it to 2d, either (1,3) or (3,1).  The third digit controls which.  Details of how it works are a bit complicated.

You can look at the code yourself at `np.lib.index_tricks.AxisConcatenator`.

In my tests '0,2,1' is like the default, so is '0,2,-3'.  Other positive values produce an error, other negative ones behave like 0.  '-5' is the same as '-6' in my tests.

```
In [46]: np.r_['0,2,-5', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape                                                             
Out[46]: (6, 1)
In [47]: np.r_['0,2,-6', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape                                                             
Out[47]: (6, 1)
```

For a 3d expansion, the 3 possibilities are:

```
In [48]: np.r_['0,3,-1', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape   # (1,1,3)                                                            
Out[48]: (2, 1, 3)
In [49]: np.r_['0,3,0', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape    # (3,1,1)                                                          
Out[49]: (6, 1, 1)
In [50]: np.r_['0,3,1', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape    # (1,3,1)                                                          
Out[50]: (2, 3, 1)
```

In the case of a (2,3) shape array expending to 3d, the alternatives are (2,3,1) or (1,2,3).  It can't insert a new dimension in the middle.

```
In [60]: np.r_['0,3,0', np.ones((2,3))].shape                                                                
Out[60]: (2, 3, 1)
In [61]: np.r_['0,3,-1', np.ones((2,3))].shape                                                               
Out[61]: (1, 2, 3)
```

===

With `ndmin` the 2nd integer, the desired dimensions, each array is expanded with:

```
newobj = array(item, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=ndmin)
```

then the 3rd integer is applied via a transpose.  The transpose parameter is calculated with an obscure piece of code:

```
                k2 = ndmin - item_ndim
                k1 = trans1d
                if k1 < 0:
                    k1 += k2 + 1
                defaxes = list(range(ndmin))
                axes = defaxes[:k1] + defaxes[k2:] + defaxes[k1:k2]
                newobj = newobj.transpose(axes)
```

A couple of versions back, `trans1d += k2+1`, so it changed from one array to the next - `-5` to `-3` to `-1`.  It ended up trying concatenate a (3,1) with a (1,3), raising the ValueError.

I found this bug fix by looking at the 'blame' mode of the https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blame/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py file:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/e7d571396e92b670a0e8de6e50366ba1dbee3c6e

> BUG: Fix mutating state between items in np,r_

Comment: So for a limited range it behaves like a modulus, though that isn't actually used in the calculation.

Comment: thks. I know the expand process.
`In my tests '0,2,1' is like the default, so is '0,2,-3'.`
It's right about default, in [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) . **In other words the third integer allows you to specify where the 1’s should be placed in the shape of the arrays that have their shapes upgraded. By default, they are placed in the front of the shape tuple.**  I cann't understand `0,2,-3`. The length of shape tuple is '2', why can use '-3', abs(-3) > 2. Even we can use `np.r_['0,2,-1000001', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape` 。

Comment: `In [6]: np.r_['0,2,-5', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a081000a6200> in <module>()
----> 1 np.r_['0,2,-5', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ].shape

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    338                 objs[k] = objs[k].astype(final_dtype)
    339
--> 340         res = self.concatenate(tuple(objs), axis=axis)
    341
    342         if matrix:
ValueError: all the input array...
`

Comment: Is your `numpy` version old enough (1.15) to be affected by this bug: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/e7d571396e92b670a0e8de6e50366ba1dbee3c6e.  Even a developer, Eric W, admits the handling of `trans1d` is a bit obscure.  My advise - use the smallest values that give the desire result, and don't worry about other possible values.